# Animation in Web Sites - Studies?

Tags: usability

In the field of Web Dev, I've heard plenty of blogs and people say that users tend to ignore (or be irritated by) content which is flashy/unnecessarily animated, adversely affecting usability, but are there any studies to support that statement?

Comment: Based on a one-man survey I just conducted, I can say that 100% of the interviewees confirmed that statement.

Comment: I agree, I tend to ignore such content myself/become irritated by it

Comment: @klausbyskov - Why do I get the impression this wasn't exactly a [double-blind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_experiment) experiment? ;)

Comment: What? My one-man surveys are known to have Gartner-level credibility! :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a couple that seem to be along the lines you are looking for. Unfortunately if you are not associated with a research institute you will probably have to buy a subscription to the journal to get your hands on the papers. As a general note it doesn't seem to be a huge area of research, but those papers should at least give some keywords and references to guide guide further search.

[Does animation in user interfaces improve decision making?](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=238396)

[The Usability of Multimedia Interface Based on User's Mental Models](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/freesrchabstract.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4089233&queryText%3Danimation+user+interface%26openedRefinements%3D%2a%26searchField%3DSearch+All)

[Evaluating the Effects of Animations on Mobile Application Learnability](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F5445539%2F5445587%2F05445699.pdf%3Farnumber%3D5445699&authDecision=-203)

[Animations in user interface design](http://www.centigrade.de/en/blog/article/animations-in-user-interface-design-essential-nutrient-instead-of-eye-candy/)

UPDATE:

This one might also be useful

[Multiple Usability Evaluations of a Program Animation Tool](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1845877.1846170)

And on a somewhat unrelated note, but since you started talking about user interfaces and usability

http://www.parc.com/event/412/wired-for-interfaces.html

Comment: Thanks! These look like they come from good source at least; I'll see if I can bark up a Uni prof's tree and _read_ them :P +1

Comment: Yeah, they seem to be ok. The PARC talk is free and at least the first PDF seems to be as well. Happy reading.